# Chat transcripts should show moderator diamonds

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, moderators

If you join any chatroom on [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) you will see something like the following:

[image]

You can view a record of past messages sent in a chatroom by looking at its transcript:

[image]

The names of moderators have a special diamond icon next to them to indicate that they are above the rest of us. You can see this in the above screenshots where Dharman's name is.

However, in the chat transcript, you can see that this icon is missing. I think that the icon should be in the transcript to distinguish moderators from the "regular" users.

Comment: Looks like room owners also aren't marked in the transcript.

Comment: This is by design, so this should be a feature request if you want it added, rather than a bug. The status of the user (e.g. mod or RO) is shown dynamically on the page only, not recorded to the database, since it can change, sometimes repeatedly, and at any time.

Comment: Moderators I don't really see the value of seeing the icons, they're just participants like everyone else. Room owners maybe yes, it might give a clue into why particular chat interactions went the way they did. But with a little brain power that should also be easy to deduce from the transcript itself to be honest.

Comment: Well, chat hasn't been touched since, like, 2016? Chances of a change here are basically non-existent. I see how this could be made into a userscript, though.

Comment: @TylerH "since it can change": when somebody said something at a time that they were a mod then such a message carried "mod weight" in the context of the conversation, so imo it would be good to reflect that in the transcript. If they are not a mod anymore later then that doesn't change the fact that they made the remark in their capacity as a mod.

Comment: @Marijn but one of the things always mentioned to aspiring and new moderators is that *everything* they ever said (in terms of comments/answers/questions) suddenly gets the diamond applied retroactively. That diamond is also removed from their posts when they no longer are mod. Keeping mod-status logged in the chat archive would thus be inconsistent with the main site.

Comment: @Adriaan the transcript is currently also inconsistent with the main site, because it doesn't show the diamond for active moderators (which inspired this meta question). I guess it would be preferred to be inconsistent while providing more information (i.e., this person was a mod at the time and may or may not be a mod now) as opposed to being inconsistent and not showing any information on which persons are currently a mod.

Comment: @Marijn I'm not suggesting one way or the other is right, only why the current implementation is the way it is.

Comment: User names can change too. In fact, more users will change their names than will become/unbecome mods/ROs. Why do we keep *those* if don't keep the diamonds?

Comment: @richardec are those kept?

Comment: @Braiam Yes, the username at the time the chat message is posted is kept in chat transcripts. It's one of the ways non-moderators can find a user's old usernames. It's one part of the dead-naming problem on Stack Exchange. [Here](//chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=7878661#7878661) is an example transcript link to one of [this user's](//chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-anonymous-hedgehog) old messages. [I picked that user as an example merely because I'm aware they change their username on an irregular basis.]

Comment: For what it's worth, SE in general doesn't do well in denoting that anywhere, [even when the user is more important than a mod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347859/244695)

Comment: @Makyen For what it's worth, that link isn't valid anymore since I've changed my name back to the one used at the time. (Also, yes, I'm OK to be used as a safe example to not out anyone who doesn't want to be deadnamed.)